# How to remove a row based on a condition in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a following dataframe:

| Index | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Tab tab_1 of type yyy opened by User A |
| 1 | some_value |
| 2 | Tab tab_1 of type xxx opened by User B |
| 3 | Tab tab_4 of type yyy opened by User A |
| 4 | some_value |
| 5 | Tab tab_1 of type yyy closed by User A |
| 6 | some_value |
| 7 | Tab tab_1 of type xxx closed by User B |
| 8 | Tab tab_2 of type yyy closed by User A |
| 9 | some_value |
| 10 | Tab tab_3 of type zzz closed by User C |

I would like to remove rows where cells in the "Description" column do not have a pair. By pairs I mean i.e. rows 0 and 5, and 2 and 7. Rows 3, 8 and 10 do not have their pairs - Certain tab IS opened by a certain user and IS NOT closed or IS closed but IS NOT opened.

Expected output:

| Index | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Tab tab_1 of type yyy opened by User A |
| 1 | some_value |
| 2 | Tab tab_1 of type xxx opened by User B |
| 4 | some_value |
| 5 | Tab tab_1 of type yyy closed by User A |
| 6 | some_value |
| 7 | Tab tab_1 of type xxx closed by User B |
| 9 | some_value |

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function `duplicated`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

For instance:

`df_new = df.duplicated(subset=['Description'])`

Answer (score 0):

honestly i'm not sure is it what you need but anyway you can try this:

```
mask = (df.groupby(df['Description'].str.replace('opened|closed','',regex=True))['Description'].
        transform(lambda x: (x.str.contains('opened').any())&(x.str.contains('closed').any())))

res = df.loc[mask]

>>> res
'''
                                  
Index                             Description           
0      Tab tab_1 of type yyy opened by User A
2      Tab tab_1 of type xxx opened by User B
5      Tab tab_1 of type yyy closed by User A
7      Tab tab_1 of type xxx closed by User B
```

Answer (score 0):

replacing the text opened & closed with null then applying filtering (dataframegroupby method) to select where occurrence is one and then dropping it

```
data.drop(data.groupby(data['Description'].str.replace('opened|closed','',regex=True)).filter(lambda x: x['Description'].count() == 1).index)
```

```
Index   Description
    0   Tab tab_1 of type yyy opened by User A
    1   some_value
    2   Tab tab_1 of type xxx opened by User B
    4   some_value
    5   Tab tab_1 of type yyy closed by User A
    6   some_value
    7   Tab tab_1 of type xxx closed by User B
    9   some_value
```

Answer (score -1):

pandas DataFrames have method `duplicated`, which does exactly what you need: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

```py
df.drop_duplicates('Description')
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.